# Custom @Query in Spring Data Repository through multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have 4 JPA Entities as following:

Entity `Farm` :

```
@Entity
public class Farm implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idFarm;
    private String nameFarm;
}
```

Entity `SAU` :

```
@Entity
public class SAU implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idSau;
    private String nameSau;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="farm_id")
    private Farm farm;
}
```

Entity `Part` :

```
@Entity
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPart;
    private String namePart;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sau_id")
    private Sau sau;
}
```

Entity `Cult` :

```
@Entity
public class Cult implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCult;
    private String nameCult;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "part_id")
    private Part part;
}
```

I need to retrieve a `Collection` of `Cult` objects Where `farm_id = x`, I obviously can't do it by using the convention naming of methods like :

```
public Collection<Cult> = findCultByPartBySauByFarmIdFarm(Long idFarm);
```

I can't figure out how to write the custom `@Query` either for this case in Spring Data Repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Query("select c from Cult c join c.part p join p.sau s join s.farm f where f.idFarm = ?1")
public Collection<Cult> = findCultByFarmId(Long idFarm);
```

Comment: @Rallph I get this error : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select c from Cult c join part p join p.sau s join s.farm f where f.idFarm = :x]`

Comment: Oh I solved the issue, you needed a to add a `c` before `part` : `..c join c.part..`, that was the missing path. Thank you.

Comment: @dwix: sorry my fault, anway you fixed it, and I updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Another version without explicit joins.

```
@Query("select c from Cult c where c.part.sau.farm.idFarm = ?1")
public Collection<Cult> findCultByFarmId(Long idFarm);
```

I usually prefer to use this as I let the underline implementation to deal with the joins for me.

Comment: Oh thanks it worked. I tried it before but it didn't work, I think I missed something.

Comment: When the relationship is well defined like your, you just need to write the query as a normal OO approach.